# Who is this person on the picture?

Tags: 20th-century

I don't have more information, I'm sorry.

[image: historical person]

Comment: If you don't have the context of where the image was presented you're going to be in trouble.  I assume you've clipped the image down to the core and tried reverse google image search?

Comment: This is not a place to ask questions about trivia. Your question does not have any historical significance.

Comment: We do often answer somewhat similar questions, but I fear there just isn't enough information on this one. For all I know some random person got bored and drew this on a whiteboard.

Comment: The resolution is too low. At best you could be given some generalisations about the possible time period due to dress fashion and art technique.

Comment: I love that students in this lecture wear [caps](http://goo.gl/hV9Dz).

Comment: I think he is either Sherlock Holmes or Vladimir Il'ič Ul'janov.

Comment: Ugh. Such snobbery on the history stack exchange really does irk me. This is a perfectly fine question.

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit No, it's not a perfectly fine question. It's a blurry photo of a projection of a drawing where the head is about maybe 40 pixels wide. The resolution is so low and blurry that this can be pretty much any person in the world. And no context is given. I have to reverse the normal question here and ask who the heck *upvoted* this, because that makes no sense.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I think we certainly upvote the answer for managing to actually decipher the photo; but the question itself was a long-shot and trivia so -1 for it.

Comment: @LateralFractal Absolutely, I was referring to the question, not the answer.

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit - this is absolutely a very bad question, and it has nothing to do with snobbery. As Tom Au explained, without some sort of context, this question is meaningless except as pure trivia. Maybe it's the sketch of an apprentice artist of his daddy reading the paper...

Answer (score 8):

It is a sketch by Simon Maris of [Piet Mondrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_Mondrian) painting on the river Gein. 1906.

See http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Simon_Maris_-_Mondrian_painting_on_the_River_Gein.JPG

[image]

Comment: Good for you for doing the (tough) ID. An explanation of the historical significance would make it even better.